# Calling a button onClick action from another script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick

I've been stuck on this for a little while. I want to call an onClick action for a button from another script.

I.E. see the below capture. I want to call that onClick from another script.

[image]

I tried `this.transform.GetChild(0).SendMessage("onClick", number);` but I keep getting **SendMessage onClick has no receiver!** error.

Any idea what I am missing?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are sending the message to right `GameObject`? In your case the `Main Camera`, not the button. Your code works in my unity 4.6.2. You can print the name of the `GameObject` with this:

```
Debug.Log(this.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.name);
```

If the `GameObject` is the right, and the message doesn't still work you can always get the component and call the function old fashion way without messages:

```
this.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<ShopBtns>().onClick(number);
```